# Cycle through matches in ZSH history-incremental-pattern-search-backward

Tags: history, zsh

I recently switched the history search to use `history-incremental-pattern-search-backward` since it allows for patterns in the search. Here is how it is setup in my `.zshrc`

```
bindkey -M vicmd '/' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

This works great, but I can't figure out how to go to the next match from the search menu.

```
% cat foobarbaz.txt
bck-i-search: f*baz
```

Is there a key bound to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally found the right incantation. You need to map the pattern search in insert mode. This was the piece I was missing:

```
# Search backwards and forwards with a pattern
bindkey -M vicmd '/' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
bindkey -M vicmd '?' history-incremental-pattern-search-forward

# set up for insert mode too
bindkey -M viins '^R' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
bindkey -M viins '^F' history-incremental-pattern-search-forward
```

I would have used `^B` for backwards search in insert mode, but I have that mapped to something else. So now `^R` and `^F` cycle through the matches.

Comment: what does the `-M` command do? In my case even without the `-M` keyword this works great..

Comment: The `-M keymap` tells bindkey which keymap to apply the binding to. I've set it up for both insert mode and command mode.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my case I just have `bindkey '^R' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`, and it works. I also use the default `/` command in vi normal model in zsh. In that I can search the command history, and once it finds the command, it will just provide that at the command line. Then I can modify the last command if necessary.

Comment: If I use `'^R' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`, on the other hand, it will just land me to the last command that matches the search string. However, I haven't found a way to actually be able to edit the command. After finding a suitable command matching the search string through incremantal patter search, are there any specific key combinations, that I can press to be able to edit the command?

Answer (score 11):

According to the `zshzle` manual page for zsh 4.3.10, no key is bound by default. You need to add bindings to the `isearch` map, and only a few widgets are available. For instance, you can do:

```
bindkey -M isearch '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey -M isearch '^S' history-incremental-search-forward
```

Comment: `bindkey -l` does not show an `isearch` mapping

Comment: @claytron: must be a version issue: `isearch` is new in 4.3.10, while `history-incremental-pattern-search-backward` appeared in 4.3.7 (if I read the changelog correctly).

Comment: I'm using 4.3.10, not sure why it isn't there. Using the insert mode bindings worked for me though.